# What is the reason for the error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' and how can it be fixed?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having an issue getting the following code to print:

```
pizza_order = {'name': 'Matthew', 'size': 'large', 'crust': 'stuffed', 'toppings': 'sausage, bacon, beef, ham'}

orders = []
for value in pizza_order.values():
    pizza = "Thank you for your order, " + value.get('name') + "\nYou have ordered a " + value.get('size') + ", " + value.get('crust') + " crust pizza with the following toppings:\n" + value.get('toppings')
    orders.append(pizza)
print(orders)
```

The error I am getting reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 33, in <module>
    pizza = "Thank you for your order, " + value.get('name') + "\nYou have ordered a " + value.get('size') + ", " + value.get('crust') + " crust pizza with the following toppings:\n" + value.get('toppings')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Seems you don't want to iterate through all values of your dictionary (which represents a single order) but use it as it is.

Comment: Yes, I had gone through a few iteration examples beforehand and so still thought I had to go that route to go through all the values. Also, thank you for the assist with the formatting of my question as this is my first question asked on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values()` iterates of the dictionary's values - `Matthew`, `large`, etc. Since the dictionary includes a single order, you don't need a loop there - just run the `print` directly.

Comment: This worked without issue, I got rid of the iterative portion and I simply changed my print statement to:

`print("\nThank you for your order, " + pizza_order.get('name') + "\nYou have ordered a " + pizza_order.get('size') + ", " + pizza_order.get('crust') + " crust pizza with the following toppings:\n" + pizza_order.get('toppings'))`

Thank you for the prompt response.

Comment: Alternative with an f-string: `print(f"\nThank you for your order, {pizza_order['name']}\nYou have ordered a {pizza_order['size']}, {pizza_order['crust']} crust pizza with the following toppings:\n{pizza_order['toppings']}")`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong you need pizza_order as list otherwise there is no reason to create `order=[]`

```
pizza_order = [{'name': 'Matthew', 'size': 'large', 'crust': 'stuffed', 'toppings': 'sausage, bacon, beef, ham'}]

orders = []
for value in pizza_order:
    pizza = "Thank you for your order, " + value.get('name') + "\nYou have ordered a " + value.get('size') + ", " + value.get('crust') + " crust pizza with the following toppings:\n" + value.get('toppings')
    orders.append(pizza)

print(orders)
```

output:

```
['Thank you for your order, Matthew\nYou have ordered a large, stuffed crust pizza with the following toppings:\nsausage, bacon, beef, ham']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop is iterating through the pizza_order dictionary instead of the orders array.

`pizza_order.values()` returns the values of the dict `["Matthew", "large", ...]`

If you just want to display the order and add to the `orders` array you don't need to use a loop.

```
pizza_order = {'name': 'Matthew', 'size': 'large', 'crust': 'stuffed', 'toppings': 'sausage, bacon, beef, ham'}

orders = []
pizza = "Thank you for your order, " + pizza_order.get('name') + "\nYou have ordered a " + pizza_order.get('size') + ", " + pizza_order.get('crust') + " crust pizza with the following toppings:\n" + pizza_order.get('toppings')
orders.append(pizza)

print(orders)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because value is not defined.

It needs to be in the format dictionaryname.get("key") change value to pizza_order and it should work.

Append needs to be out of the loop

```
pizza_order = {'name': 'Matthew', 'size': 'large', 'crust': 'stuffed', 
'toppings': 'sausage, bacon, beef, ham'}

orders = []
for value in pizza_order:
    pizza = "Thank you for your order, " + pizza_order.get('name') + "\nYou 
    have ordered a " + pizza_order.get('size') + ", " + 
    pizza_order.get('crust') + " crust pizza with the following toppings:\n" 
    + pizza_order.get('toppings')
orders.append(pizza)
print(orders) OR print(pizza) #You choose
```

Comment: Why do you create the content of the string `pizza` 4 times? The loop makes no sense here.

Comment: @Matthias The questioner used a loop so I kept the same structure.

Comment: For me "The asker did it wrong, so I did it wrong in my answer too" isn't a good enough reason.

Comment: @Matthias Know what you're talking about.

Comment: We seem to have different meanings of what "works" means. If someone asks me how to set `i` to `100` and someone suggests `i = sum(n % 2 for n in range(200))` I'd call that "wrong". But I might have overlooked something here, so please explain why the `for` loop with the unused variable `value` is needed.

Comment: @Matthias We have different meanings of wrong not work. The code isn't wrong, whether it works has never been mentioned. You're changing the subject.

Comment: I'm not changing the subject. I'd still like to know what I asked in my first comment. Why do we need this loop? You said "I kept the same structure" but I still don't understand why it is needed in your fixed code. Maybe we should stop the discussion here.